# Is anonymize an English word?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Can I use the verb anonymize ? (related to anonym) 
Is it standard English or the kind of word only non-native English would say?

regards
Julien

Comment: Maybe a pedant would say *anonymize* is an American word while *anonymise* is an English word...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Anonymize* is a word in good standing these days, especially in connection with computers, digital privacy, and the like. It can be found in the mouths of native and non-native English speakers alike. Still, it achieved wide recognition among lexicographers as a mainstream word only fairly recently.

I say this with some confidence because it doesn't appear in the most recent print dictionary in the Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary series, the *Eleventh Collegiate* (2003), and it doesn't appear in *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fourth edition (2000).

Bit it does appear in the most recent AHDEL, *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2010), with the following entry:

> **anonymize** *tr.v.* **-mized, -mizing, -mizes** To make anonymous, especially by removing or preventing access to names: *medical records that were anonymized for use in a study.* {ANONYM(OUS) + -IZE} **—anonymization** *n.*

So AHDEL affirms not only that *anonymize* is a standard English word nowadays, but that *anonymized*, *anonymizes*, *anonymizing*, and *anonymization* are, too. Nevertheless, whether you'll find it in a dictionary depends to a very great extent on the age of the dictionary you consult.

An earlier dictionary listing for *anonymize* appears in *The Concise Oxford English Dictionary*, revised tenth edition (2002):

> **anonymize** (also **-ise**) **v.** *Medicine* remove identifying particulars from (test results) for statistical or other purposes.

This definition is particularly interesting because it suggests that *anonymize* got its start in the context of medical research (a point obliquely confirmed by the AHDEL example). Just eight years later, to judge from AHDEL's broader definition, the term seems to have escaped the laboratory and come to be applied to any instance where a person's identity is removed or obscured.

Comment: But OP shows no signs of having consulted _any_ dictionary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes—it's a pity that the poster didn't include in his question the sentence, "I checked the _Oxford American English Dictionary and Thesaurus_ (2003), and it doesn't have an entry for the word." If he had done so, we could all agree that he had performed _some_ research, and then we might reach the question of whether his question and my answer are, in themselves, potentially useful to future visitors. But alas, he didn't do that, and so the question must be closed.

Comment: Someone would doubtless have benefited from a correct answer to 'What is the best way to keep goldfish?' that appeared on ELU a few years ago. If people aren't prepared to observe the requirements, there are many other websites which might well be be more appropriate. ELU is aimed at linguists etc.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime: Single-word requests are largely exempt from the show research requirement—an anomaly that (I believe) led to formulation of the "choosing an ideal word or phrase" close reason. In any event, fill-in-the-blank requests are enormously (and surprisingly) popular with linguists, etc., as you can see by checking the three largest sources of upvotes in the [User profiles](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) on this site, where "single-word-requests" and/or "word-choice" pop up in almost every major contributor's top three.

Comment: ...Admittedly, "almost every" may be overstating the case a bit: Of the 180 site participants who have currently accumulated 8,000 or more reputation points on this site, 164 have "single-word-requests" and/or "word-choice" among their top three sources of upvotes; 16 do not. Still, even those who do not count either category in their top three have received hundreds—often, thousands—of points from them. I certainly have.

Comment: @SvenYargs I just saw your replies now because I had deleted my earlier comment.  You make a good point, I've earned plenty of points on single-word-requests and they are in my top three tags.  Either way, my beef is not really with single-word-requests but with the downvoting of answers to ostensibly bad questions.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime: When I'm satisfied with the value of an answer I've posted (which is ... usually), I find it easier to accept downvotes that aim to chastise me for not upholding someone else's standards. Of course, if the criticism were more general, I'd have to rethink my own standards—or look for a more compatible venue for answering questions. Downvoting an answer because one doesn't like the associated question is an idiosyncratic tactic, I admit, but I don't doubt the public spirited motive behind the gesture and I appreciate the forthrightness of the downvoter's accompanying comment.

Comment: @SvenYargs That's a sensible, laudable, and well-put stance on the matter.  The comportment you bring to EL&U is impressive and appreciated.

Comment: Don't you consider the putting on hold for lack of desirable and easily obtainable (a Google search for "anonymize meaning")  research sufficient support for the upholding of standards?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I look at it this way: The question is now closed, as (according to the current formal standards of this site) it should be; and I've provided an answer to it that I think is potentially more useful to interested readers than the information they are likely to find at any single, free dictionary site. I hope that future site visitors who click on this page—assuming that it isn't deleted, which certainly might happen—will find my answer helpful and informative. As I've said elsewhere, I consider the "show research" requirement an administrative convenience for close voters, ...

Comment: ... not a substantive basis for finding a question bad. When EL&U voters reject a question for lack of research, they are rejecting it pro forma, not on substance—because the rejection kicks in before they reach the question of substance. That’s why “show research” is administratively convenient—you don’t have to show that an arbitrarily selected general reference work actually provides a definitive answer, nor do you have to wrangle about whether a Google search constitutes “general reference.” All you have to do is note the lack of research and vote to close.